# Create possible combinations of specific size

Tags: python, algorithm

The string/list is e.g. 'foobar'. I need to break this up in all possible combinations where the number of groups is n, e.g. 3.

This would give me e.g.

```
['foo', 'ba',  'r']
['f',  'ooba', 'r']
['fo', 'oo',   'bar']
['f',  'o',    'obar']
```

etc

What is the best algorithm to create all the possible combinations?

Comment: Hint: think about the separators between the groups. Negative space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import combinations

def compositions(s,k):
    n = len(s)
    for c in combinations(range(1,n),k-1):
        yield [s[i:j] for i,j in zip((0,)+c,c+(n,))]
```

The way it works is that the `combinations` part yields tuples which consist of possible cut points. For example (with `s = "foobar"` and `k = 3`) `(2,4)` is one of the tuples. Breaking at these indices should yield `["fo","ob","ar"]` which corresponds to `[s[0:2],s[2,4],s[4,6]]` the expression `zip((0,)+c,c+(n,))` in this case is the same as `zip((0,2,4),(2,4,6))` hence iterating over it has the effect of iterating over the the successive pairs of indices for the successive slices.

For example,

```
>>> for c in compositions("foobar",3): print(c)

['f', 'o', 'obar']
['f', 'oo', 'bar']
['f', 'oob', 'ar']
['f', 'ooba', 'r']
['fo', 'o', 'bar']
['fo', 'ob', 'ar']
['fo', 'oba', 'r']
['foo', 'b', 'ar']
['foo', 'ba', 'r']
['foob', 'a', 'r']
```

I chose the name "compositions" since you are essentially talking about [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) in combinatorics. My algorithm was based on the proof in the linked article that the number of compositions of n items into k pieces is `C(n-1,k-1)`.

Comment: Replace `combos.append` with `yield` and this becomes marvelous. You could explain a little bit the `zip((0,)+c,c+(n,))` part.

Comment: @arekolek Good idea, definitely more in keeping with the spirit of itertools. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Also, you forgot about the `combos = []` line, which you don't need anymore.

Comment: @arekolek - fixed, with an explanation added

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple recursion

```
def split(s, n):
    def rec_split(i, s, n):
        ans = []

        if n == 1:
            ans.append([s[i:]])
            return ans

        for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
            head = s[i:j]
            tails = rec_split(j, s, n-1)
            for tail in tails:
                ans.append([head] + tail)
        return ans

    return rec_split(0, s, n)

for e in split("foobar", 3):
    print(e)

# ['f', 'o', 'obar']
# ['f', 'oo', 'bar']
# ['f', 'oob', 'ar']
# ['f', 'ooba', 'r']
# ['fo', 'o', 'bar']
# ['fo', 'ob', 'ar']
# ['fo', 'oba', 'r']
# ['foo', 'b', 'ar']
# ['foo', 'ba', 'r']
# ['foob', 'a', 'r']
```

`rec_split` returns all partitions of `s` in `n` parts from the `i`-th index onward

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Word break](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-solution-word-break/) algorithm, this is a variant of it with a significant difference that words don't come from a predefined dictionary, but instead there need to be a fixed number of them in a final set.

The main idea is to iterate through your input from the beginning, slice it and process the right part recursively.

Assuming the function with a prototype

```
def rec(input, n):
```

this is a pseudo code:

```
if n == 1:
    final_set.append([input[i:]])
else:
    for i in range (0, len(input) - n + 1):
       for rec_set in rec(input[i:], n - 1):
           final_set.append(merge(input[:i], rec_set))
```

Using your example, we have:

```
rec('foobar', 3)
= {['f', rec('oobar', 2)], ['fo', rec('obar', 2)], ['foo', rec('bar', 2)], ['foob', rec('ar', 2)]}

= {['f','o', rec('obar', 1)], ['f','oo', rec('bar', 1)], ['f','oob', rec('ar', 1)], ['f','ooba', rec('r', 1)], ['fo', 'o', rec('bar', 1)], ['fo', 'ob', rec('ar', 1)], ['fo', 'oba', rec('r', 1)], ['foo', 'b', rec('ar', 1)], ['foo', 'ba', rec('r', 1)], ['foob', 'a', rec('r', 1)]}

= {['f','o', 'obar'], ['f','oo', 'bar'], ['f','oob', 'ar'], ['f','ooba', 'r'], ['fo', 'o', 'bar'], ['fo', 'ob', 'ar'], ['fo', 'oba', 'r',], ['foo', 'b', 'ar'], ['foo', 'ba', 'r'], ['foob', 'a', 'r']}
```

The important thing to remember is to **cache** partial results in order to avoid repeat doing same job over and over. For example, if you already calculated `rec('oobar', 2)` store the result in some cache (e.g. dictionary is suitable for this) and check at the beginning of the function whether you have already calculated all possible combinations for the specified input string and `n`. It reduces time complexity from exponential to polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) for this. Generate all possible splits and backtrack whenever you've split the word into more than three parts.

Comment: This could be a valuable answer if you provided a bit more detail of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this recursively with a generator:

```
def sections(s, n):
    if n == 1:
        yield [s]

    if n > 1:
        for i in range(1, len(s)):
            for tail in section(s[i:], n - 1):
                yield [s[0:i]] + tail
```

and use it like this:

```
for s in sections("foobar", 3):
    print s
```

Comment: Oops, it's the same function. Changed the name before posting, which I shouldn't have done, of course. Edited the post.